# The optimal function value in linear programming has analytic solution

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following linear programming problem:

$\min c'x$ subject to $Ax=b$ and $x\geq0$, where $A$ is $m\times n$ with rank$A=m$.

The dual is $\max -b'v$ subject to $A'v+c=\lambda$ and $\lambda\geq0$.

It seems that if we assume that the optimal function value is not $-\infty$, we have an analytic solution for this optimal function value: $b'(AA')^{-1}Ac$.

Proof:
Since rank$A=m$, the only $v$ satisfying $A'v+c=\lambda$ is $v=(AA')^{-1}A(\lambda-c)$.

If we plug this into the dual, we get  $-\min_{\lambda\geq0} b'(AA')^{-1}A(\lambda-c)$. Notice that if any vector $s\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $\min_{z\geq0} s'z$ is equal to $-\infty$ if $\min_i s_i\leq0$ and is equal to zero otherwise.

Since we know the optimal function value is not $-\infty$, it follows that the optimal function value is $b'(AA')^{-1}Ac$.

Am I missing something here? I thought linear programs are not supposed to have analytic solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since rank$A=m$, the only $v$ satisfying $A'v+c=\lambda$ is
>   $v=(AA')^{-1}A(\lambda-c)$.

This is true, but it not all that useful. After all, non-trivial linear programs have $m<n$, so the equation $A^Tv+c=\lambda$ is *underdetermined*. There is no guarantee whatsoever that, for a given $\lambda$, there even exists a value of $v$ satisfying $A^Tv+c=\lambda$. These constraints describe an affine space of potential values of $\lambda$.

What this means is that you *cannot eliminate the constraints from the dual problem* as you have done when you try to express it as  $-\min_{\lambda\geq0} b'(AA')^{-1}A(\lambda-c)$. There are plenty of values of $\lambda$ that cannot be considered because of the above restriction.

You've removed essential dual constraints without a correct justification. The science of linear programming is preserved!

Comment: That's right! Thanks!